# :first-child applying to all links

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I am trying to remove the margin-left:10px; from the first menu item in my main navigation. I am ussing a wordpress custom navigation for my site.

I have tried the :first-child method but this seems to remove the margin for all links not just the first. Is there another method you know of that can do this? Below is the html for my menu:

```
<div class="menu-links">
    <div class="menu-menu-1-container"><ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu"><li id="menu-    item-4" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-4"><a href="http://hadston.immaculate.co.uk/">overview</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-6"><a href="#">Strategy</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-7"><a href="#">business</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-8"><a href="#">leadership</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-9"><a href="#">governance</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-10"><a href="#">csr</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-   item-11"><a href="#">sustainability</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12"><a href="#">careers</a></li>
</ul></div>        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
ul.menu li,a {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;
padding-bottom:5px;
margin-left: 10px;
}
ul#menu-menu-1 > li,a:first  {
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This is more of a CSS question... and you haven't posted your css selectors.

Comment: added my css. sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
ul#menu-menu-1 > li,a:first  {
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

You need to apply the first-child to the list element, and not to the link. You should also not have a comma. Comma indicates a new selection.

Try this:

```
ul#menu-menu-1 > li:first-child a{
maegin-left:0px;
}
```

*first-child does not work in ie8 and earlier.

Comment: Great! Having said that, you should ask CSS questions at stackoverflow.com - you would get an answer much faster there. Questions here should be related to Wordpress. I know you are using wordpress but the question is not about wordpress itself.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, this is a CSS-specific question.
Here is one approach to do this, anyway:

```
/* Reset left margin for ALL items  */
ul.menu li {
    margin-left: 0;
}

/* Set it back for any item that's not the first one */
ul.menu li + li {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Depending on your current CSS, you might have to change the selectors (e.g., use a specific class name for the list items).

Comment: added my css. sorry about that. i will try what you have provided.